# Enabling click action for links in Android Textview

Tags: android, textview

I need to enable click action for links in Textview and open the webpage in app window. Linkify will open in browser.But I want to open in a webview in my app. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [blog post](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/10/29/clickable-urls-in-android-textviews/) that talks about extending ClickableSpan.

First extending the ClickableSpan class:

```
static class InternalURLSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    OnClickListener mListener;

    public InternalURLSpan(OnClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        mListener.onClick(widget);
    }
}
```

The blog talks about the clickable link doing something in your activity.  You can easily adapt this approach to open the URL in a WebView.

It would essentially look something like this:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("....")
ss.setSpan(new InternalURLSpan(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Your code to open the link in a WebView here.
        }
    }), x, y, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

You would just set the SpannableString object as the text of your TextView:

```
textView.setText(ss);
```

Comment: I have getting dynamic text from a web service as Google.com or something else. How can I detect whether it is a web url or not

Comment: If you yourself are not creating the content, you're going to need to parse through the content and replace links with the clickableSpan as above.   If you're ultimately just going to be opening the clicked links in a webView, why not load the initial web service information into a webView?  That way, the webView would handle all the clicks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can underline textview through string.xml file

```
<string name="hello_world"><u>Hello world!<u></string>
```

Now you can set onClickListener on your textView and can redirect user to your webView Activity instead of browser app.